# How can I change the Features in Shader Editor?

Tags: python, shaders, shader-nodes

how can I change a property in a shader editor in a blender file?

I know the code I wrote is ridiculous, but I'm new to the blender library.

```
import bpy

setattr(Height, Scale, 2500)
```

[image: My Shader Editor View]

Comment: you want to use bpy.data.materials["material_name"].node_tree.nodes["Height"].inputs["Scale"].default_value = somthing. not posting as answer because I'm rusty on the syntax, and no one else has answered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be able to identify the material and then the specific node within the material and then the specific input for the specific node within the material.  Since there is no "Height" Node, I'm assuming that's a Noise texture node, with its label (not name) changed to "Height".

There are many ways to get to the right input, depending on where you are in your code.  There's a comment on your question that suggests one approach that would work if the Node's name was "Height", but assuming that the name hasn't changed and the label is "Height" instead, you can only get part way there:

```py
nodes = bpy.data.materials["material_name"].node_tree.nodes
```

will give you a list of nodes in the material.  Next you have to iterate through the list to find the specific node you want.  Here's one approach

```py
work_node = None
for node in nodes:
    if node.type == 'TEX_NOISE' and  node.label == "Height":
        work_node = node
```

Because 'TEX_NOISE' is they type of a noise texture node.

Now that you know that, you can set the default value:

```py
if work_node:
    work_node.inputs["Scale"].default_value = 2500
```

Comment: Thank you very much your answer. Worked.

Comment: You're very welcome.